# Need help identifying this SMD

Tags: power-supply, transistors, power, integrated-circuit, surface-mount

[image: 3 pins with code CG and a Y written horizontally]

I don't know what this component is. It's found on an adblue ECU for Citroen. I suspect it's faulty and need to order it.

Comment: What makes you think it is bad?  The brown stuff is just flux from when the board was assembled.  The photo is rather fuzzy, but nothing looks obviously damaged.  You can't really test a part that is still on the board - any measurements you've made are suspect because the part is on the board.

Comment: Given that there are two seemingly identical parts, perhaps remove both and buzz them out to see how they behave?  Not transistors I’m guessing as the base/gate would be connected to a plane, but perhaps dual diodes?

Comment: Set your multimeter to diode mode and try every combination. Which combination(s) shows a diode voltage drop?

Comment: There are many of these on the circuit. One is connected to a mosfet 2n7002. The left pin for that is connected to a negative supply while the middle pin on the other side is connected to a positive side. The right pin for that isn't connected to anything. The letterings are CG with a Y stamped horizontally. On the other identical board, it's CG with a horizontally stamped U.

Comment: The adblue ecu board doesn't communicate on the canbus. It works intermittently when the relay switches on. I had a board that didn't work for 2 years until I scraped off the conformal coating (maybe fluke) and it worked for a month before dying again. When I removed the mosfet and installed it back, the relay worked for 10 mins and so did the canbus. The next day it didn't.  Then I removed the TVS diode and it did the same. Relay switches on and next day it doesn't.